How can I make my icon overflow its container?
I want the inner span to be centered in .icon and overflow it.
This seems to work when I use display: inline-block:


.icon {
  line-height: 1.2;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: clip;
  overflow-clip-margin: 1.2em;
  background-color: red;/*for debugging*/
}
<span class="icon"><span style="display: inline-block; width: 30.1699px; height: 8.48528px; background-color: currentcolor;"></span></span>



 black box width is correct, but it's not centered over the red box


.icon {
  line-height: 1.2;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-flex;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: clip;
  overflow-clip-margin: 1.2em;
  background-color: red;
}
<span class="icon"><span style="display: inline-block; width: 30.1699px; height: 8.48528px; background-color: currentcolor;"></span></span>



 centered but won't overflow now
How can I get it both centered and have it overflow?

almost good, add flex-shrink:0 to the inner span element

you need to ensure that the inner span is correctly positioned in relation to the parent container.
.icon {
  line-height: 1.2;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block; /* Use inline-block to maintain the flow with text */
  position: relative;    /* Relative positioning allows absolute positioning within */
  overflow: clip;        /* Use clip to allow overflow without scrollbars */
  overflow-clip-margin: 1.2em;
  background-color: red; /* For debugging */
}

.icon > span {
  display: inline-block; 
  position: absolute;   /* Absolute positioning */
  left: 50%;            /* Center horizontally */
  top: 50%;             /* Center vertically */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Adjust for exact centering */
  background-color: currentcolor;   /* For debugging, sets to current text color */
}



<span class="icon">
  <span style="width: 30.1699px; height: 8.48528px;"></span>
</span>

